# PHP - 'print/echo' displaying closing tags - or not outputting

Tags: php

Starting some PHP and confused by the way echo/print are working.

I've got this code in my `index.html`:

```
<?php
Print '<div>Hello, World!</div>';
?>
```

And the output on my page is

```
Hello, World!'; ?>
```

If I remove the `<div>` tags, I get no output. using `echo` produces the same behaviour.

What's going on? Everything I find on Google makes it seem straight forward.

Comment: Is this file included by others? There might be an unclosed string in another file if it _is_ included.

Comment: Have you modified the php.ini some way? What have you changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot put PHP code in an HTML file (unless you tell Apache to parse HTML files).

Rename the file to index.php

Do you have a webserver with PHP set-up?

Comment: You right. But i don't understand how can that be, he is trying to use PHP on an HTML file. So, it must output whole code as a string. But it's just outputting `Hello, World!'; ?> ` .

Comment: Because the browser sees this as an HTML tag: "<?php
Print '<div>". Opening and closing brackets

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'm running Apache configured for PHP, but hadn't configured it to parse HTML files. Renamed it to .PHP and it's working fine.

Comment: *"Rename the file to index.php"* - It looks like something more needs to be done. I'm following the [PHP Hello World tutorial](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php.general/2JkglcoPc1o). I have similar code in `index.php`, and I'm getting the same results.